# Error 500 when copying Google Doc that contains drawings

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-docs-api

I'm trying to create a copy of a Google Docs file into a directory. The user selects both the file and directory using the Google Picker API and I can confirm that my service has access to the selected file, directory.

For copying I use Google API PHP Client:

```php
$copy = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
   'name' => $name,
   'parents' => [$directoryId]
]);
$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($this->googleClient);
$driveResponse = $driveService->files->copy($fileId, $copy);
```

The code works fine with most files. However, some users have embedded drawings in their files. On copying such file, I receive the 500 error:

> message: "Internal Error"
> domain: "global"
> reason: "internalError"

Right now I use the `drive.file` scope. I figured it might have something to do with drawing being inaccessible with the limited scope. So for my testing I switched the scope to `drive.readonly`, and it worked.

But then I tested it with a file that literally has nothing but a drawing of a straight line that is represented as an EmbeddedObject: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#embeddedobject. And it returns 500 error unless the scope is `drive.readonly`.

**Question:** Why can't I create a copy of Google Doc file that has embedded drawings using the `drive.file` scope? Is switching scope my only solution?

Comment: Here's the bug in the issuetracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/281787010